# Setting a trigger on a programmatically created Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am building a Google sheets platform where I make a new spreadsheet for a new user by copying a template spreadsheet. Because of a potential large amount of users, I need to be able to do this programmatically.

Part of the template is an `onEdit` trigger. So far I have not found a way to copy this trigger to the new spreadsheet. I have tried by using `ScriptApp.newTrigger` as shown below:

```
var newss = playertemplate.copy(playerid + '. ' + playername).getId()
var newsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newss).getSheetByName('Sheet1')
var newfile = DriveApp.getFileById(newss)

newfile.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT)

ScriptApp.newTrigger("submitBets").forSpreadsheet(newss).onEdit().create()
```

But the result is that the new trigger is created both on the "master" spreadsheet from which the above script is run, and on the new spreadsheet. I have found that this works for up to 20 new users, after which I run into the limit of the number of bound triggers on the master spreadsheet. When I remove the trigger on the master spreadsheet, it is removed on the new one as well.

I have found some old similar questions but none of them were solved, so I'm hoping a solution was developed in the past few years or someone found a workaround in the meantime.

Comment: When exactly you want to run this trigger? On File Edit only? Also why do you want to create new trigger in newly created file? On the master file add a menu clicking on which should create a new file for you.

Comment: @DarpanSanghavi Yes, the trigger should run on edit. The new spreadsheet which I am copying from the template is a spreadsheet where people enter their predictions for matches in a gaming tournament. Those predictions should then be synchronized with the master spreadsheet on edit.

Can you explain more about the menu item? How would that help me copy the template including the trigger?

Comment: I am afraid then you will get at most 20 triggers only. Please refer [Appscript quota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) once.

Comment: How about creating an Add-on and publishing it? This will create a new trigger under the new user's name. So it won't consume from your ID.

Comment: It says 20 per user per script. The way I interpreted it, if I copy a spreadsheet a new script project is generated so I would be able to attach 20 triggers per user spreadsheet.

Comment: Add-on may be an option. But I think the trigger needs to run from my ID because the script needs access to the master spreadsheet which only I have access to. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: Yes that's correct assumption. Let me try few possibilities. Will post if I found a way.

Comment: You can have access to a master spreadsheet using two scripts. First script would be an add-on that uses the [fetch function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)) over a second script published as a web app, listening to doGet() and doPost() functions. That second script can have access, modify and serve reserved data as requested from the first script. I have a few apps running like this and works perfect.